# JSONDecodeError while running pyspark and flask_ngrok on google colab

Tags: flask, pyspark, google-colaboratory, ngrok

I am running pyspark to retrieve a table called *books_df* from S3 and convert it to a spark dataframe to use it further in my application.
Pyspark Code:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/content/drive/<<path to curr dir>>/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop2.7"
findspark.init()
conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setAppName('appName').setMaster('local')
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
spark = SparkSession(sc)
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
df = spark.createDataFrame(books_df)
df.show(3)
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+
|        book_authors|           book_desc|        book_edition|book_format|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+
|     Suzanne Collins|Winning will make...|                null|  Hardcover|
|J.K. Rowling|Mary...|There is a door a...|          US Edition|  Paperback|
|          Harper Lee|The unforgettable...|    50th Anniversary|  Paperback|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+
only showing top 3 rows
```

flask_ngrok section:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,redirect, url_for, request, session, abort, flash
from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='/content/drive/<<path to curr dir>>/templates',static_folder='/content/drive/<<path to curr dir>>/static')
run_with_ngrok(app)

@app.route('/')
def upload():
   return(render_template('upload.html'))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

When running this, I get the following error:

```
* Serving Flask app "__main__" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
Exception in thread Thread-25:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 1177, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flask_ngrok.py", line 70, in start_ngrok
    ngrok_address = _run_ngrok()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flask_ngrok.py", line 36, in _run_ngrok
    j = json.loads(tunnel_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

***Important note:*** When I add `sc.stop()` after the pyspark section, flask_ngrok works perfectly fine but I cannot access the pyspark dataframe *df* as the sparkContext is closed.

Is pyspark and flask_ngrok trying to access the same port and thus, giving the error?